# Building WP_Query args for multiple authors in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

In Javascript, I'm building a set of arguments to pass to `WP_Query` by AJAX and they are all working, except for one. Below is the code:

```
if( blogFilters['authors'].length > 1 ){
    var authorsArray = [];
    for (i = 0; i < blogFilters['authors'].length; i++) {
        authorsArray.push( blogFilters['authors'][i] );
    }
    args['author__in'] = authorsArray;
} else if( blogFilters['authors'].length > 0 ) {
    args['author_id'] = blogFilters['authors'][0];
}
```

If 'authors' has only one item, the query is working correctly. However, if it has multiple authors - the query is not working and is returning all posts, regardless of author.

I know what the query should look like in PHP, as per the [WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters), but I'm having trouble figuring out the syntax to correctly build it in javascript. I've also tried:

```
args['author__in'] = blogFilters['authors'].join(',');
```

But that didn't work either.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to filter by multiple authors but only the first author in the array is being filtered in the loop.